# annoying issue with auto-layout

Tags: xcode, cocoa, autolayout

I have a big annoying problem with auto layout sheet, if I try to change some value, width, click on standard or change from equal to less o bigger than the outlet was disabled, than if I want to modify the outlet I have to reselect e do the modific...this is very annoyng, some solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution, but getting used to the appropriate keyboard shortcuts makes the workflow a little bit faster.

**Cmd-Alt 4** shows the Attribute Inspector.

**Cmd-Alt 5** shows the Size Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to start creating my views and windows programmatically. Auto Layout makes creating controls in code much more compelling.

1. The Interface Builder user interface is a train wreck with Auto Layout. It takes forever to get things set up correctly. Often changing unrelated items shifts items you were done with, restarting the cycle of fixing things.. again.
2. Auto Layout removes the need to use frames and sizes when creating controls in code. It used to be that creating controls in code were hard to size and place appropriately. Now it's a breeze using auto layout format strings
3. Creating controls programmatically allows you to do a cleaner MVC.
4. Creating controls programmatically makes refactoring easier. Instead of typing strings into Interface Builder for your object properties, you can use constants.